# SQL - Combining all children in one row

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to move data from a database into a pandas data frame. I have data in multiple tables that I want to combine.

I'm using SQLAlchemy and relationship between parent/children.

I'm trying to understand how I'd do this in SQL before attempting in SQLAlchemy

I am using Sqlite as a DB.

```
parent_table
ID | Name | Class
1  | Joe  | Paladin
2  | Ron  | Mage
3  | Sara | Knight

child1
ID | distance | finished | parent_id
1  | 2 miles  | yes      | 1
2  | 3 miles  | yes      | 1 
3  | 1 miles  | yes      | 1
4  | 10 miles | no       | 2

child2
ID | Weight | height | parent_id
1  | 5 lbs  | 5'3    | 1
2  | 10 lbs | 5'5    | 2
```

I want to write a query where the result would be everything for `Joe` (id: 1) on a row.

```
1 | Joe  | Paladin | 2 miles  | yes  | 3 miles | yes  | 1 miles | yes  | 5lbs  | 5'3
2 | Ron  | Mage    | 10 miles | no   | None    | None | None    | None | 10lbs | 5'5
3 | Sara | Knight  | None     | None | None    | None | None    | None | None  | None
```

I'm guessing I need to do a join, but confused about the fact that `Ron` has less `child1` entries.

How do I construct a table that has as many columns as needed and fills out the empty ones as `None` when some of the rows in `parent_table` don't have as many children?

Comment: What database platform is this for?

Comment: sqlite, just updated the question

Comment: This will be helpful: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html.

Answer (score 0):

simply search everyone by themself and use a union to join:

```
SELECT Name,Class FROM parent_table WHERE ID = 1
UNION 
SELECT distance,finished FROM child1 WHERE parent_id = 1
UNION
SELECT weight,height FROM child2 WHERE parent_id =1
```

This way you avoid the problem for Ron or anyone that does not have a register in a table,

Answer (score 0):

You can't have "As many columns as needed" because the number of child rows is variable and you can't have a variable number of columns. If you can figure out a fixed number of children, (say 2) you can do:

```
    CREATE TABLE
        "some_table" 
    AS
        SELECT
            "parent_table"."ID",
            "parent_table"."Name",
            "parent_table"."Class",
            "child1_1"."finished" AS "2_miles",
            "child1_2"."finished" AS "3_miles"
        FROM
            "parent_table",
            "child1" AS "child1_1",
            "child1" AS "child1_2"
        WHERE
            "child1_1"."parent_id"="parent_table"."id" AND
            "child1_2"."parent_id"="parent_table"."id" AND
            "child1_1"."distance"='2 miles' AND
            "child1_2"."distance"='3 miles'
```

You can add columns from child2 in the same manner. And child subkeys (data in `child1.distance` i.e.) will need to go to column names. But for variable one-to-many relations, you need multiple tables. It's basically what the relational concept is all about.

For data analysis (which you are trying to do as it seems) you will also need two datasets (like tables) because the 2 measurements (sample sets) are not correlated (i.e. distances and weights), which you can obtain in 2 tables. Think of what a "sample" is (the result of a measurement). It can't be "entity 1 completed 2 miles and 4lbs" because "2 miles and 4 lbs" it's not a measurable event. So you have 2 distinct samples: "entity 1 completed 2 miles" and "entity 1 completed 4 lbs". (Or are the data in child2 1-to-1 properties of the entity in `parent_table` ? You should detail better the meaning of the data and what you-re trying to achieve).